# Serializing Entities with Associations

Tags: json, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have an entity (Item) that has a many to one relationship to another entity (Type) declared here:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="item")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $itemType;
```

And when I serialize items, it includes other attributes on the referenced entity (Type) when all I wanted was just the ID:

```
item_type: {
     id: 1
},
```

instead with this:

```
item_type: {
     id: 1,
     name: "Case & Cover",
     description: "Keep your phone safe with stylish cases and covers"
},
```

I've read the documentation and tested with groups and maxdepths but no luck, and browsing through issues i've encountered this:
 https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/61#issuecomment-3297955

is this feature already included?

using `"jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master"`

**EDIT**

this is the sample serialized entity with association(s):

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "iPhone 5c Slim Genuine Leather Portfolio Case with Stand - Classic Black",
    price: 29.95,
    description: "...",
    image: "1.jpg",
    item_type: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Case & Cover"
    },
    item_brand: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Apple"
        }
    ]
}
```

what I really wanted was this(without any extra attributes of an associated entity): (using JMS Serializer since it is an awesome library:) )

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "iPhone 5c Slim Genuine Leather Portfolio Case with Stand - Classic Black",
    price: 29.95,
    description: "...",
    image: "1.jpg",
    item_type: {
        id: 1
    },
    item_brand: [
        {
            id: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the exludePolicy for the entity `Type` `@ExclusionPolicy('all')` and add `@Expose` to the `id` property.

see the documentation http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations

Hope it's helpful

Best regard.

Comment: yep that is what I did, I actually included the `@ExclusionPolicy('all')` before the class. But I need the other attributes on another controller but just the (Type) entity without any associations and I needed to exclude the other attributes on an entity with associations except the id